# RadGrid Pages is duplicated?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, grid, telerik

Hi All:
I had an RadGrid with enable paging , when the end user clicks previous page(radgrid has one item) the pager appears at top and bottom (RadGrid Position set to Bottom).

Is There any way to solve this problem??

Comment: Very weird, looks like a problem with the viewstate. How do you define the grid, do you switch its page mode dynamically? Post your code and I will do my best to help you out.